# JQuery script doesn't work when html code is put in php if/else condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xampp

I am working on a project to create a form generator which dynamically adds the required form fields. I have used `JQuery` to add fields or `append fields` dynamically to a division when buttons are clicked. The entire mechanism including the script works perfect until `the html code is added` in a `php if/else` condition (working with sessions). Php is somehow stopping the script from running. I have tried rearranging the code but to no use.

The file in which the appending or the preview takes place (build_form.php):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="build_form.css">       
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $k=1;
            if($k==1)
            {

        ?>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="build_form.js"></script>

        <div id="full">
            <div id="left">
                <div id="formElements">FORM ELEMENTS</div>
                <div id="name">
                    <button class="formButtons" id="btnName" onclick="appendName()">Name</button>
                </div>
                <div id="email">
                    <button class="formButtons" id="btnEmail" onclick="appendEmail()">Email</button>
                </div>
                <div id="address">
                    <button class="formButtons" id="btnAddress" onclick="appendAddress()">Address</button>
                </div>
                <div id="Phone">
                    <button class="formButtons" id="btnPhone" onclick="appendPhone()">Phone</button>
                </div>
                <div id="Submit">
                    <button class="formButtons" id="btnSubmit" onclick="appendSubmit()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <div id="yourForm">YOUR FORM</div>
                <div id="preview"></div>
                <script>$("#preview").sortable();</script> <!-- makes the divisions inside the division with id #preview sortable-->
                <div>
                    <form method="post" action="build_file.php" id="form1">
                        Enter form name:<input type="text" name="f_name"><input type="submit" value="Create Form" onclick="createForm()">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

    </body>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</html>
```

***build_form.js***

```
var name=1;
var email=1;
var address=1;
var phone=1;
//$("#preview").sortable();
function appendName()
{
    var code="<div class='preBox'><label>Name</label><input type='text' name='name"+name+"'><button class='temp' onclick='remove(this)'>Remove</button></div>";
    $('#preview').append(code);
    name = +name + 1;      // + is used to show that the variable is a number
}
function appendEmail()
{
    $('#preview').append("<div class='preBox'><label>Email</label><input type='email' name='email"+email+"'><button class='temp' onclick='remove(this)'>Remove</button></div>");
    email = +email + 1;
}
function appendAddress()
{
    $('#preview').append("<div class='preBox'><label>Address</label><input type='text' name='address"+address+"'><button class='temp' onclick='remove(this)'>Remove</button></div>");
    address = +address + 1;
}
function appendPhone()
{
    $('#preview').append("<div class='preBox'><label>Phone</label><input type='text' name='phone"+phone+"'><button class='temp' onclick='remove(this)'>Remove</button></div>");
    phone = +phone + 1;
}
function appendSubmit()
{
    $('#preview').append("<div class='preBox'><button type='submit' form='form2'>SUBMIT</button><button class='temp' onclick='remove(this)'>Remove</button></div>");
}
function remove(btnId)
{
    var divId=btnId.parentNode;
    $(divId).remove();
}
function createForm()
{
    $(".temp").remove();
    var fCode=$("#preview").html();
    $('#form1').append("<div><input type='hidden' name='fCode' value='"+fCode+"'></div>");
}
```

> The entire mechanism stops working when the html code is added in
>   if/else condition in build_form.php. File name or extension is not
>   the issue but the conditional statements are the issue (tested it).

It should work like what's shown in the image. Fields should be added when buttons on the left is clicked but it stops working when `if/else` condition is used.
[image]

IMPORTANT: **The Code doesn't work even if I remove the php code later (starts working when I delete the files and paste new copies). It's like a permanent effect.**

Comment: as a 1.2k user I'd expect some indentation - this is hard to read :(

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: no worries :) Just make sure the code is easy to read, allows a quicker response time :)

Comment: your closing of "if" is outside the body tag it should be inside

Comment: @KarthikGanesan It still doesn't work. :( It was inside initially.

Comment: try using `===` instead of `==` - `==` checks for all dataTypes, try using strict comparison and seeing if that makes a difference :)

Comment: @MathewsMathai try adding your if statement after your script tags, also are there any errors in console once you add your php code?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Script tags where outside the php tags initially. I rearranged to check if this works but it doesn't. No errors.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs That doesn't work either. I don't understand what's happening here. The script does not start working even when I remove the `php code`. :( It's like a permanent effect. It continues working when I replace the files with fresh copies.

Comment: Have you tried hard clearing cache?

Comment: Yeah. Tried that too. :(

Comment: @MathewsMathai that is odd, try recreating the file as test.php / test.js etc. and run it from a 100% new url in private window to see if it runs - if it still doesn't then you have a fatal syntax error somewhere

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs It started working when I used `$( document ).ready()' function (wrote the entire script inside this function). But it stopped working with the function when further changes were made to the script and now it works without the function. I think it is somehow related to behaviour of the script and page loading.

Comment: @MathewsMathai always have everything inside $(document).ready :) but I think you're right - must be sometihng to do with how the script is loading